# Conntrack: How to track connection in one direction

Tags: iptables

I have the following iptables rule.

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o vEth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I want conntrack to to track connections that are going out of vEth0. And with the above rule I'm able to do that.

But, I do not want to track any incoming connections on the i/f. So I added another rule,

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i vEth0 -j CT --notrack
```

But now, the outgoing connections are not tracked anymore by conntrak. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is the purpose of disabling connection tracking just on one way?